# With Bootstrap 5, show text of checkboxes and show active item in dropdown

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I am trying to recreate the layout of a site (created with Streamlit) with Bootstrap 5.

The Streamlit site looks like this:

[image: Streamlit site]

where the dropdown contains the following values:

[image: dropdown]

I am a first time Bootstrap user, so am I just copy/pasting examples from around the web.

Currently I have:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap">
      <div class="col-auto col-md-3 col-xl-2 px-sm-2 px-0 bg-light">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center align-items-sm-start px-3 pt-2 text-white min-vh-100">
          <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center pb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-white text-decoration-none">
            <span class="fs-5 d-none d-sm-inline">Menu</span>
          </a>
          <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-sm-auto mb-0 align-items-center align-items-sm-start" id="menu">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link align-middle px-0">
                <i class="fs-4 bi-house"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Select agent
                                    type</span>
              </a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <div class="btn-group m-1" role="group" aria-label="Type">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-hornets dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Select agent type
                                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" data-value="1" href="#">MRKL</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" data-value="2" href="#">ReAct</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" data-value="3" href="#">Self-Ask-With-Search</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                <i class="fs-4 bi-people"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Select tools</span>
              </a>
            </li>

            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckChecked" checked>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked">
                                textbooks
                            </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckChecked" checked>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked">
                                reports
                            </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckChecked" checked>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked">
                                documentation
                            </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckChecked" checked>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked">
                                notes
                            </label>
            </div>
          </ul>

          <hr>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col py-3">
        <form action="" class="form-inline mt-5" id="chat-form" onsubmit="sendMessage(event)">

          <div class="chat-body card">
            <div class="card-body p-5">
              <h4 class="card-title text-center text-xl font-medium"> Chat Your Data </h4>
              <p class="card-text text-center text-sm" id="header"> Ask a question </p>
              <hr class="border-gray-500 mb-5" style="margin-top: 20px;">
              <div id="messages" class="overflow-auto" style="max-height: 500px;">
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Write your question" id="messageText">
              <button id="send" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

which has the following problems:

- the text of the checkbox items is not visible
- the dropdown shows the text `Select agent type` instead of the selected item
- When I remove the `<a>` tags around `Select agant type` and `Select tools`, those items are no longer visible.

The colors in my implementation are also different and the right hand side also looks slightly different but that is less important.

How do I resolve this?